# Any way to compare multiple Google analytic Accounts

Tags: google, google-analytics, reporting

I have a Google analytic's account on my website that makes use of 10 properties.

Each property has its own tracking code.

In few words, my website displays 10 different Google analytic tag scripts. Each tag has its own purpose.

I'm searching for the best way to see a report that could compare all of the channels.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Why not setup event tracking which will let you categorize and tag each element you're tracking either with mouse clicks or virtual page views rather than having multiple tracking codes on one page?